# read BLOB from mysql using php PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, blob

I have a database with a BLOB field (weeklyOccupancy).  I am trying to access the data in PHP using:

```
$sqlCmd = 'select weeklyOccupancy from Occupancy order by startDate;';
$pdoStmt = $dbh->query($sqlCmd);
$pdoStmt->bindColumn(1, $lob, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$pdoStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);
foreach($pdoStmt as $row){
    $weeklyData = stream_get_contents($lob); 
    ....
}
```

However, stream_get_contents says that $lob is a string (named "Resource id #1) although I believe it should be a stream.  I have seen this mentioned as a bug (http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php#96311) but the workaround is not relevant for my application - in which the blob holds a bit string not an image to be displayed.

Any ideas how I can get the data out of a blob field in PHP?  Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Not all PDO drivers return a LOB as a file stream; mysql 5 is one example.  You can try treating `lob` as a string after the bind.

Comment: I am happy to treat it as a string; however, I need to know the function which allows me to retrieve the data from the DB.

Answer (score -1):

Oops.  There was an earlier error in my code.  Problem gone.