# reading blob from mysql database with php

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I do the following in my php code :

```
$q="SELECT * FROM {$table} where x;
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "test", "test","mytable");
$res = mysqli_query($link,$q);
 if($res)
   {
       $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
       header("Content-type: text/xml");
       header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
       echo $row['blob'];
   }
```

I can see that the data(xml file) that I uploaded into mysql does not have any leading spaces but when I run the above code 3 new lines and a space appear and the file is not well formed xml any more.
Any idea why the exact contents are not being read from the table?

Comment: Have you looked in the MySQL database to see if there are new line characters there, this will rule out the script as an issue. How is the XML not well formed anymore. Do you mean there are tags missing etc, or do you mean the  browser no longer interprets the XML as XML. Or do you mean it isn't indented properly?

Comment: Store XML as text, blob's are for binary data.  On that note, don't store XML..

Comment: XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity
Line Number 3, Column 2:

Comment: which is supposed to be in the first line is on line 3 column 2

Comment: @Chris I looked at the MySQL DB and there are no new lines there.It is funny how I get these new lines when I read them using php.

Comment: @bigman Could you please elaborate.Is there no other workaround ?

Comment: Post the xml - then we can see what you are working with

Comment: Even if I store just <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> in the DB it turns out to be   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> with two lines and one column in front  @Chris

Comment: was going to suggest trim - then read rkstar's suggestion

Comment: @bigman even on changing to 'text' from 'blob',I see the same problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [read BLOB from mysql using php PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920007/read-blob-from-mysql-using-php-pdo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.A silly mistake.
My open php tag started on line 3 column 2

```
> <?php
```

and that made the 'echo' starting from the same line (line 3 column 2).
Is that how echo is supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

You should investigate where the extra newlines are coming from, but you could get around your problem by running:

```
trim($row['blob']);
```